# Is the "curvature matrix" a tensor for non-affine connections?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm reading about connections in chapter 4 of Chern's *Lectures on Differential Geometry*. In section 4-1, he defines the curvature *matrix* on generic vector bundles to be
$$
\Omega = d \omega - \omega \wedge \omega
$$
where $\omega$ is the connection matrix.

It seems to me that the curvature matrix $\Omega$ is a tensor, i.e., at point $p\in M$, $\Omega(p)\in V^*_p \otimes V_p \otimes T^*_p\otimes T^*_p$ where $V$ is the typical fiber.

Is this correct?

What's very confusing to me is that Chern never states (at least in section 4-1) that $\Omega$ is really a tensor. In section 4-2, he focuses on affine connections and finally defines the curvature tensor $R^j_{ikl}$, but from my reading, he doesn't actually mention that $R^j_{ikl}$ are precisely the coefficients of the curvature matrix in the standard basis $du^i \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial u^j} \otimes du^k \otimes du^l$. This seems super fundamental - something that ought to have been highlighted, if true.

Comment: Did you mean to put *curvature* matrix in your question's title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in general, the curvature of a vector bundle $E$ is a $2$-form with values in $\operatorname{Hom}(E,E)$. Chern pretty much says this explicitly in the second paragraph following Definition 1.2 on p. 108.

Comment: Thanks. I was just confused by the presentation. This is such a fundamental idea, yet it wasn't clearly spelled out and this made me second guess my understanding. Instead of just plainly saying $\Omega$ is a tensor, he spends considerable effort to construct the curvature operator $R(X,Y)$, which he clearly states *is* a tensor. Yet once you know $\Omega$ is a tensor, $R(X,Y)$ is a simple construction. (You're just multiplying the $T^*_p(M)\otimes T^*_p(M)$ indices of $\Omega$ by $X\wedge Y$.)